# Connect Ubuntu to Wifi

Tags: 14.04

I am having trouble with my recently installed Linux Ubuntu. Why cant i connect Ubuntu to Wifi? It will try to connect then asks for the password every thirty seconds. Can someone please help. Btw i am using a Edimax wirless usb adapter and already have the drivers it, but it doesn't even recognize that I have it in the comupter.

Comment: Please [run the WiFi diagnostics](/a/425205/175814) and [edit] your question to include a link to the result.

Answer (score 0):

You need to install the drivers for your device.

I took a guess on which device you have(if I got it wrong, just do a Google search for Edimax wireless usb adapter -INSERT MODEL NUMBER HERE- drivers linux)
[This](http://www.edimax.com/au/support_detail.php?pd_id=347&pl1_id=1&pl2_id=#01) is the driver that I found. Scroll to the bottom and click the Linux download.

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu, It isn't recommended to answer a question with speculative information such as guessing what network card is being used. It is better to either ask in the comments when you have enough reputation or wait for somebody else to ask and retrieve the relevant information when the question is edited to include said information.